# Main activity variable becoming null

Tags: android

In my main activity I have:

```
private DataManager mDataManager;
```

In the same activity I manage this variable following the lifecycle. These are the related methods:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mDataManager = new DataManager(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDataManager.connect(getIpAddress());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mDataManager.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mDataManager = null;
}

@Override
public DataManager getDataManager() {
    return mDataManager;
}

@Override
public void updateFragments() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mLoading.isShowing())
                mLoading.dismiss();
            List<Fragment> allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
            if (allFragments == null || allFragments.isEmpty())
                return;
            for (Fragment fragment : allFragments)
                if (fragment.isVisible())
                    ((UpdatableFragment) fragment).updateView();
        }
    });
}
```

I have some fragments that use `getDataManager()` to update themselves with data, but sometimes, often when I do not use the application for a while I get a `nullpointerexception` because `getDataManager()` returned null. According to the activity lifecycle, the object should never be `null` or am I missing something?

EDIT: Initialization of the ViewPager

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    MainAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return FragmentX.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return FragmentY.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return FragmentZ.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return FragmentU.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: move `mDataManager = null;` to `onDestroy()`

Comment: I could be wrong, but the above comment does not seem correct to me. [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) . Is there anywhere else in the code, that may be setting it to null?

Comment: @Doomsknight is right. The crash will not be fixed by onDestroy() call. Are your fragments part of a viewPager?

Comment: Did you check the code with breakpoints that will surely give you the answer you are looking for ?

Comment: I guess you are calling `getDataManager()` from `OnCreateView()` that is the only place where it could return `null`.

Comment: @Doomsknight I believe you are correct, but based on the supplied code by the OP that was my best guess, as a comment, that might help.

Comment: @nnn: yes the fragments are managed by a viewpager... why?

Comment: @Doomsknight: nope, it's set as null just there

Comment: @MarkKeen I wouldnt worry about it. We are all here to help :) . There is definately something out of the scope of code posted, that is causing it to be null. nullpointer, did you check where you are calling getDataManager from? has the onStart() method been called by that point?

Comment: Post your code where you are initializing your ViewPagerAdapter. I think you are passing getFragmentManager() to the ViewPagerAdapter instead of getChildFragmentManager().

Comment: @nullpointer17 : Try replacing getSupportFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentManager() while initializing MainAdapter.

Comment: @nullpointer17: Please let me know if it works for u.

Comment: I can't use getChildFragmentManager, with the AppCompatActivity class... i added also the method i use to update the fragments